# Attaching a new graphic card (GPU) or Changing another component(s) of the desktop computer to resolve high frequencty of freeze

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

My desktop computer has been getting tend to freeze with high frequency so I've been trying to buy some new component(s).

I bought the computer during Jan~March 2016

GPU is 3~5 years.

Motherboard and cpu is ~6 years.

So I bet that I should buy a new gpu or motherboard.

So, as gpu inside the motherboard is not broken, there is 2 options .

One of which is to attach a new gpu to the motherboard.

The other one is to change the motherboard.

I know that doing both is best for solution for freeze but at this time I want to try one of them.

Which way is best you think?

[image]

```
Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Voltage: 1.1 V
External Clock: 100 MHz
Max Speed: 3600 MHz
Current Speed: 3200 MHz
Status: Populated, Enabled
Upgrade: Other
L1 Cache Handle: 0x003A
L2 Cache Handle: 0x003B
L3 Cache Handle: 0x003C
Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Core Count: 4
Core Enabled: 4
Thread Count: 4
Characteristics:
    64-bit capable
    Multi-Core
    Execute Protection
    Enhanced Virtualization
    Power/Performance Control
```

[Memory(4_GB)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WVSLBHG)

[motherboard(H110M-A)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016A47K6Q)

I attached the [graphic card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AZ7W88O)

I will report the result of it soon.

***After the installtion of the [graphic card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AZ7W88O)***

The smoothness has been seemingly bit ameliorated but not a complete solution.
The resolution of the display has been greatly improved but I don't want it. I just want a smoothness with no freeze.

The freeze occured from gradual less smoothness.

I think I may should have bought cpu rather graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an overheating of the CPU due to a poor transfer of heat between the CPU and its cooler. I have the same issue with my Dell laptop I'd buy some thermal paste, I will link a paste that I personally use for my high-end gaming system, and you would replace the thermal paste from the cooler and cpu. You would want to make sure all of the old paste Is off the cooler and the CPU before you apply the new paste. You'd apply a large pea-sized dot in the center and then re-mount your cooler.

[Thermal Grizzly Kyronaut Thermal Paste](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011F7W3LU)